# In xcode, can I make random() or arc4random choose from a set?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Suppose I have a list of numbers, ie. (240, 320, 640, 920) and I want to select one of these four numbers at random.  Can I do this with random or arc4random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int values[4] = {240, 320, 640, 920};
int value = values[random() % 4];
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but you'll need to use an array:

```
int numbers[4] = {240,320,640,920};
int random = numbers[(arc4random()%4)];
```

By the way, `arc4random()` is a lot better than `random()` because it doesn't need to be seeded.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily, not directly with random or arc4random. Store the numbers in an array and select a random number using random or arc4random in the range of 0 to length(array) - 1. Then use that number as the index of the array. And this technique will work in any place, not in just iPhone.